VirtualBox does not pass the avx512 processor command to the guest system
I use Ubuntu 24.04 as the host system and Ubuntu 24.10 in the VirtualBox as a guest system.
Although my processor in the host system supports the command avx512, it is not passed on to the guest system.
My processor is:

11th Gen Intel® Core™ i9-11900 × 8

Is there a way to make the processor of the host system completely available for the guest system in VirtualBox?

There are several posts online regarding this topic. What research have you done and what have you tried so far regarding this?

After the current state, I see 3 possibilities: 1. The problem is with VirtualBox.2. The problem is at Ubuntu 24.10. 3. The problem lies in the interaction of Ubuntu 24.10. and VirtualBox. Currently - so today - I have installed the latest version from everything.  With the previous versions, especially Ubuntu 24.04 everything worked. So my next step will be to go back to the version Ubuntu 24.04 and see what happens. :-) ; I could not find further setting options from VirtualBox, so here my question.

My current solution is that I went back to Ubuntu 24.04 as a guest system.
Ubuntu 24.04 obviously does not use the processor command avx512 and there is probably no possibility to configure Virtualbox version 7.1.2 r164945 (Qt6.4.2) to enable it to reach this command from the host system to the guest system.
